# Boost::asio::async_read_until never calls handler

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, tcp, boost-asio

I am trying to build a connection between two computers on a local network, one using a slightly modified version of the Boost Asio C++ TCP asynchronous server sample, the other one using NodeJS.

#### tcp_client.js :

```
var net = require('net');
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var PORT = 14002;

var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {
    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT);
    // Write a message to the socket as soon as the client is connected
    //the server will receive it as message from the client 
    client.write('Hello');
});

// Add a 'data' event handler for the client socket
// data is what the server sent to this socket
client.on('data', function(data) {
    var fs = require('fs');
    fs.writeFile("test.txt", data, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        client.write("Data written"); // returns successful
        console.log("The file was saved!");
    }); 
});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});
```

#### tcpServer.cpp :

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

extern string _coordinates;

using namespace std;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string inline make_daytime_string() {
    std:: time_t now = std::time(0);
    return std::ctime(&now);
}

class tcp_connection
    // Using shared_ptr and enable_shared_from_this
    // because we want to keep the tcp_connection object alive
    // as long as there is an operation that refers to it.
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
    {
    public:
        typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

        static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) {
            cout << "Creates a pointer for the tcp connection" <<endl;
            return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
        }

        tcp::socket& socket() {
            return socket_;
        }

        // Call boost::asio::async_write() to serve the data to the client.
        // We are using boost::asio::async_write(),
        // rather than ip::tcp::socket::async_write_some(),
        // to ensure that the entire block of data is sent.

        void start() {
            while(1) {
                start_read();

                // This is going to read after every 1ms the _coordinates variable
                usleep(1000);

                m_message = _coordinates;

                boost::asio::async_write(
                    socket_,
                    boost::asio::buffer(m_message),
                    boost::bind(
                        &tcp_connection::handle_write,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                    )
                );
            }
        }

private:
    tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : socket_(io_service)
        {
        }

    void start_read() {
        // Start an asynchronous operation to read a newline-delimited message.
        // When read, handle_read should kick in
        boost::asio::async_read_until(
            socket_,
            input_buffer_,
            '\n',
            boost::bind(
                &tcp_connection::handle_read,
                shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );
    }

    // When stream is received, handle the message from the client
    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {

        std::cout << "HANDLE_READ - line 101" << "\n";
        messageFromClient_ = "";
        if (!ec) {
            // Extract the newline-delimited message from the buffer.
            std::string line;
            std::istream is(&input_buffer_);
            std::getline(is, line);

            // Empty messages are heartbeats and so ignored.
            if (!line.empty()) {
                messageFromClient_ += line;
                std::cout << "Received: " << line << "\n";
            }
            start_read();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error on receive: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }
    }

    // handle_write() is responsible for any further actions
    // for this client connection.
    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/) {
        m_message += "helloo\n";
    }

    tcp::socket socket_;
    std::string m_message;
    boost::asio::streambuf input_buffer_;
    std::string messageFromClient_;
};

class tcp_server {
    public:
        // Constructor: initialises an acceptor to listen on TCP port 14002.
        tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 14002))
        {
            // start_accept() creates a socket and
            // initiates an asynchronous accept operation
            // to wait for a new connection.
            start_accept();
        }

private:
    void start_accept() {
        // creates a socket
        cout << "creating a new socket for the communication" <<endl;
        tcp_connection::pointer new_connection = tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

        // initiates an asynchronous accept operation
        // to wait for a new connection.
        acceptor_.async_accept(
            new_connection->socket(),
            boost::bind(
                &tcp_server::handle_accept,
                this,
                new_connection,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );
    }

    // handle_accept() is called when the asynchronous accept operation
    // initiated by start_accept() finishes. It services the client request
    void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection, const boost::system::error_code& error) {

        if (!error) {
            cout << "Starting the new tcp connection" <<endl;
            new_connection->start();
        }

        // Call start_accept() to initiate the next accept operation.
        start_accept();
    }

    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};


int inline launch_server() {
    try {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;
        tcp_server server(io_service);

        // Run the io_service object to perform asynchronous operations.
        io_service.run();
    }
    catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sending the message from the C++ to NodeJS works (the `async_write(..)` in the `start()` while loop, which sends `_coordinates` every 1ms), but **I can't manage to handle the messages coming from my NodeJS program** :

When running (both programs on my computer, on localhost), the output of `ss -tp | grep 14002` (14002 being the port), the Recv-Q/Send-Q of the NodeJS process are empty (and the `socket.write(...)` returns successful), while, for the C++ part, the Recv-Q is constantly growing and Send-Q is empty
Moreover, when running, all the `cout ..` of the `handler_read()` are not printed, which means that the `async_read_until()` function never calls the handler.

I tried all the overload versions of the `async_read_until()`, none of them works. And, as the messages are not of constant size, it seems that i have no choice but to use read_until.

I hope I didn't forget any useful information. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically saturating your CPU with the infinite while loop in your `tcp_connection::start` method. Not only that it is saturating the CPU, it is also a bug in your design. Why would you want to continuously attach handlers for read and also send/write data to the socket in a infinite loop ? Most probably you want to `write` to the socket after receiving a request from the client.

Below are the methods I changed to make it work like a regular client-server:

```
void start() {
          start_read();

          // This is going to read after every 1ms the _coordinates variable
          usleep(1000);
          m_message = _coordinates;
        }

void start_read() {
        // Start an asynchronous operation to read a newline-delimited message.
        // When read, handle_read should kick in
        boost::asio::async_read_until(
            socket_,
            input_buffer_,
            '\n',
            boost::bind(
                &tcp_connection::handle_read,
                shared_from_this(),
                boost::asio::placeholders::error
            )
        );
    }

void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& ec) {

        std::cout << "HANDLE_READ - line 101" << "\n";
        messageFromClient_ = "";
        if (!ec) {
            // Extract the newline-delimited message from the buffer.
            std::string line;
            std::istream is(&input_buffer_);
            std::getline(is, line);

            // Empty messages are heartbeats and so ignored.
            if (!line.empty()) {
                messageFromClient_ += line;
                std::cout << "Received: " << line << "\n";
            }
            start_read();
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "Error on receive: " << ec.message() << "\n";
        }

        start_read();

        boost::asio::async_write(
                    socket_,
                    boost::asio::buffer(m_message),
                    boost::bind(
                        &tcp_connection::handle_write,
                        shared_from_this(),
                        boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                        boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred
                    )
                );
    }
```

I am not sure what you are 'actually' trying to do based on the question as it stands now, but the above changes should be a good point to start with.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Indeed, my CPU was saturated. 

In fact, the write/read parts are separated :

- the server should write in the socket every millisecond the content of `_coordinates`

- the client should send be able to send a message when needed : currently it is just a "data received" message, but later it will be some JSON strings to launch specific functions of my program (on the server side) when using buttons on the HMI linked to the JS part.

Then, where should I implement the (updating _coordinates + write on socket) loop that has to be done every millisecond ?

Comment: Yes, you can use a `deadline_timer` for writing every x milliseconds. Later if you find it not scaling as per your requirements  (or your read handler starts turning out to be more expensive or blocking) then you can consider about using multiple threads for your writes and read

Comment: Thank you very much, @Arunmu ! I used `deadline_timer` for writing, and it works as expected (considering that I don't have a need for precision).